# Conditional lambda function on a filter()

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I have a problem with the filter() function. I decided to use a lambda function to discriminate if a value is within a threshold on a tuple

```
lambda_tuple = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)

filtered_lambda = filter (lambda x: x if (x <= 3) else (False), lambda_tuple)
```

Then I iterated and printed every item

```
for item in filtered_lambda:
    print ('item = ',item)
```

And got the next output

```
item =  1
item =  2
item =  3
```

Given the condition `(x <= 3)` the value `0` should pass the filter.

Any thoughts on why isn't passing the `0`?

Comment: as an aside, these are really strange variable names

Comment: In any case, I think you misunderstand how the predicate function is supposed to work. You return `x` when `x <= 3`, so when `x` is `0`, you return `0`, the truthiness of `0` is false, so that element is not provided by the filter iterator. You seem to be treating the function as if it were a cross between a predicate and a mapping function

Comment: So the function you want is just `lambda x: x <= 3`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because filter only returns Truthy values and since `0 == False`, it is never returned by filter function.

This is the description for the `filter` function from the Python docs.

> Construct an iterator from those elements of iterable for which function returns true. iterable may be either a sequence, a container which supports iteration, or an iterator. If function is None, the identity function is assumed, that is, all elements of iterable that are false are removed.
>
> Note that filter(function, iterable) is equivalent to the generator
> expression (item for item in iterable if function(item)) if function
> is not None and (item for item in iterable if item) if function is
> None.

So I think the affirms my initial thoughts.

You could use list comprehension instead of `filter` if you need the `0` to be included.

```
>>> lambda_tuple = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
>>> filtered_lambda = [i for i in lambda_tuple if i <= 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```